# Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported using Flask-Sqlalchemy and MySQL

Tags: mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm connecting to MySQL (8.0) database with Flask here's the error:

```
Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

I created the database 'user' by this sql command:

```
ALTER USER 'my_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
flush privileges;
quit;
```

I keep getting the same error though. How can I address this?

I suspect the legacy plugin can no longer be used as I tried to include it in `my.cnf` file and the MySQL server failed to start after relaunch.

Comment: no this works still and your code has no errors, so please post the **exact and complete** error message

Comment: @nbk The exact error output:  `sqlalchemy.exc.NotSupportedError: (mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError) Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/tw8g)`

Comment: Please stop using and publishing 'flush privileges' with ALTER USER or SET PASSWORD or any standard user change, its not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using this uri helped in my case:

`'mysql+mysqlconnector://user:password@localhost/db?auth_plugin=mysql_native_password'`